# Haxe (hxcpp) – Path relative to executable path

Tags: haxe, hxcpp

Say I have following file structure of my application:

```
Data/prefs.ini
executable.exe
```

How can I open prefs.ini providing relative path to it from executable.exe is always the same (known at compile time)? Or how can I get absolute path of executable.exe? I need it to work on Linux, Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an exact haxe API for that: `Sys.executablePath()` ([doc](http://api.haxe.org/Sys.html#executablePath))

To get a path relative to it:

```
import haxe.io.Path;
class Test {
    static public function relToExe(path:String):String {
        return Path.join([Path.directory(Sys.executablePath()), path]);
    }
    static function main() {
        trace(relToExe("something"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have been blind